# Is support@pi.uk.com the real blockchain.info's support address?

Tags: blockchain.info

Currently blockchain.info lists that address in the "about us" page, but since the site is behaving erratically, I wonder if it's the real address or a phony one.

I.e. if the site was hacked, the address would likely be replaced with one the attacker has access to, so the info provided on the site itself is not very useful to determine if that address is genuine.

Comment: Blockchain.info (i.e., Qkos Services LLC) is still a one-person operation and that one-person is traveling at the moment (presumably for his previously announced plan to team up with someone and build epic Bitcoin stuff).  Here's the latest: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=40264.msg875431#msg875431

Comment: @StephenGornick sure, that was not to be intended as a criticism, I simply wanted to be sure that address was really his own.

Comment: It's worth noting that this question and answer could be edited by a number of people...

Comment: @HighlyIrregular sure, but the history remains

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the address I used to contact Ben Reeves (blockchain.info's author) a few months ago, so it should be correct. Whether it is still in his control is a different question. He is also known as [piuk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=17928) in the bitcointalk forums.

Comment: Furthermore that address is written in the whois record, too.

Answer (score 4):

I reported a bug to that address just a week ago and had it fixed immediately:

> From: Ben Reeves <support@pi.uk.com> via gmail.com Apr 23 (7 days ago)
>   To: Chris
>
> Chris,
>
> Thanks for the heads up. This should be fixed now.
>
> piuk

I've used the same address many times in the past, too.  Sometimes I don't get a reply, sometimes I do.